# How to start a Google Fit Activity via intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-fit

I have developed a custom Android Wear watch face to be a Soccer Referee timer. Now I'd like to integrate with with Google Fit. As my first baby step, I just want to start a Google Fit Activity at the same time as I start the timer for the kickoff of a game. In other words, I don't want to create Fit sessions or collect sensor data myself (yet); I just want to save users the step of swiping to Fit Activity and starting it themselves.

It seems that I should be able to broadcast an intent to do this, but can find no documentation on the appropriate format. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Google Fit [broadcasts intents](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions#session_broadcast_intents) when any app starts or stops recording a session on behalf of the user. It also supports different [intents](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/Fitness#intents) that are defined in class like [`public static final String ACTION_TRACK`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/Fitness.html#constants) action where the user can request an application to start or stop tracking their activity.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this. But I get no such Activity errors if I try to start Google Fit that way. My conclusion right now is that I should use the Session API to start a Google Fit session.